# how does for loop work in command prompt

Tags: for-loop, cmd

How does a for loop work in command prompt. what is the function of delimiter and tokens in for loop. please explain me in detail or give me some link where it is explained

Comment: [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) & [robvanderwoude.com](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php)

Comment: type `for /?` at a cmd prompt.

Comment: Here is my favorite FOR link: http://judago.webs.com/batchforloops.htm